# How to handle Events in CheckedListBox in C#?

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I'm new to `C#`. I tried to perform activities when items in `CheckedListBox` is clicked. I tried 
`private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(Object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
}`
but nothing working. Now please anyone tell how to display the checked items text in `MessageBox`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it windws from ??

Comment: refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes in windows form @Pranay Rana

Comment: also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.itemcheckeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString()); //This gets the displayed name of the checked items
        }
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString()); //This Displays the index of the checked items
        }
    }
```

And this is the method that runs if you check an item.

```
        private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Does this answer your question?